# How to merge deep value in array of objects

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have an array with objects and I want to combine all values of params inside the objects into one object

```
Array [
  Object {
    "key": "Deze week",
    "params": Object {
      "thisWeekfilterDistance": [Function anonymous],
      "thisWeekSearch": [Function anonymous],
      "thisWeektoggleFilter": [Function anonymous],
      "thisWeektoggleRangeFilter": [Function anonymous],
    },
    "routeName": "Deze week",
  },
  Object {
    "key": "Binnenkort",
    "params": Object {
      "soonfilterDistance": [Function anonymous],
      "soonSearch": [Function anonymous],
      "soontoggleFilter": [Function anonymous],
      "soontoggleRangeFilter": [Function anonymous],
    },
    "routeName": "Binnenkort",
  },
  Object {
    "key": "Festivals",
    "params": Object {
      "festivalfilterDistance": [Function anonymous],
      "festivalSearch": [Function anonymous],
      "festivaltoggleFilter": [Function anonymous],
      "festivaltoggleRangeFilter": [Function anonymous],
    },
    "routeName": "Festivals",
  },
]
```

I have tried this

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (typeof arr[i].params !== 'undefined') {
            //console.log(arr[i].params);
            test = arr[i].params;
        }
    }
```

or

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   arr[i].param.reduce(function(result, current) {
     return Object.assign(result, current);
   }, {})
}
```

but i don't know how to store the results of those to get only 1 object with all object params.

So the expected result is:

```
{
      "thisWeekfilterDistance": [Function anonymous],
      "thisWeekSearch": [Function anonymous],
      "thisWeektoggleFilter": [Function anonymous],
      "thisWeektoggleRangeFilter": [Function anonymous],
      "soonfilterDistance": [Function anonymous],
      "soonSearch": [Function anonymous],
      "soontoggleFilter": [Function anonymous],
      "soontoggleRangeFilter": [Function anonymous],
      "festivalfilterDistance": [Function anonymous],
      "festivalSearch": [Function anonymous],
      "festivaltoggleFilter": [Function anonymous],
      "festivaltoggleRangeFilter": [Function anonymous],
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Post code, data structures, markup, and other textual information **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: Some doc here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: never,same key name of the single Object may not possible

Comment: Please post the [code as text and not as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3082296). Images can't be copied to create an answer. Also, your expected output is invalid

Comment: I have posted a text code instead of an image, and as i said the key names will be unique inside the code.

Comment: The expected output still has duplicate keys

Comment: i have updated the expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get an array of `params`. Then use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to merge the array of objects to a single object:

```js
const input = [{"key":"Deze week","params":{"thisWeekfilterDistance":_=>{},"thisWeekSearch":_=>{},"thisWeektoggleFilter":_=>{},"thisWeektoggleRangeFilter":_=>{},},"routeName":"Deze week",},{"key":"Binnenkort","params":{"soonfilterDistance":_=>{},"soonSearch":_=>{},"soontoggleFilter":_=>{},"soontoggleRangeFilter":_=>{},},"routeName":"Binnenkort",},{"key":"Festivals","params":{"festivalfilterDistance":_=>{},"festivalSearch":_=>{},"festivaltoggleFilter":_=>{},"festivaltoggleRangeFilter":_=>{},},"routeName":"Festivals",},]

const output = Object.assign({}, ...input.map(a => a.params))
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do with `Array#reduce` direct array not with array object params

```js
var arr = [{ "key": "Deze week", "params":  { "thisWeekfilterDistance": "[Function anonymous]", "thisWeekSearch": "[Function anonymous]", "thisWeektoggleFilter": "[Function anonymous]", "thisWeektoggleRangeFilter": "[Function anonymous]", }, "routeName": "Deze week", }, { "key": "Binnenkort", "params":  { "soonfilterDistance": "[Function anonymous]", "soonSearch": "[Function anonymous]", "soontoggleFilter": "[Function anonymous]", "soontoggleRangeFilter": "[Function anonymous]", }, "routeName": "Binnenkort", }, { "key": "Festivals", "params":  { "festivalfilterDistance": "[Function anonymous]", "festivalSearch": "[Function anonymous]", "festivaltoggleFilter": "[Function anonymous]", "festivaltoggleRangeFilter": "[Function anonymous]", }, "routeName": "Festivals", }, ]

var res = arr.reduce((a,b)=> Object.assign(a,b.params),{})

console.log(res)
```